# RewriteEngine On - Internal Server Error

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have issue with Linux server.

Configuration:
Linux server 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u2 i686

Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)

PHP/5.4.39-0+deb7u2

ModRewrite is turned on (a2enmod)

Me htaccess looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

#RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /var/www/git

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
<Files config.ini>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

When i uncomment #RewriteEngine On i get Internal Server Error

Me sites-available in Apache looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/git
ServerName git.server.com
Alias /git /var/www/git

RewriteLog /var/log/apache2/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 5

<Directory /var/www/git>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Do you have any idea to solve the issue?
Thank you

Comment: Did you check your server error log?

Comment: Sure i have there for example: [Mon Aug 31 13:28:00 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.23] File does not exist: /var/www/git/refresh, referer: http://git.server.com/ And many like this. No more useful information.

Comment: The file doesn't exist, this true, but in this case is there htaccess. I think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with replacing /var/www/git to /

Anyway thanks for suggestions.